# Using Tablib Library with Web2py

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I've been trying for a while to make tablib work with web2py without luck. The code is delivering a .xls file as expected, but it's corrupted and empty.

```
import tablib 
data = []

headers = ('first_name', 'last_name')
data = tablib.Dataset(*data, headers=headers)

data.append(('John', 'Adams'))
data.append(('George', 'Washington'))


response.headers['Content-Type']= 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8'
response.headers['Content-disposition']='attachment; filename=test.xls'
response.write(data.xls, escape=False)
```

Any ideas??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state , `response.write` is documented as serving

> to write **text** into the output page body

(my emphasis).  `data.xls` is **not** text -- it's binary stuff!  To verify that is indeed the cause of your problem, try using `data.csv` instead, and **that** should work, since it **is** text.

I believe you'll need to use `response.stream` instead, to send "binary stuff" as your response (or as an attachment thereto).